# Real Analysis: closed set and open set

Tags: real-analysis

1) An open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}$, other than $\mathbb{R}$ itself, such that  $\mathbb{Q} \subset U$. Is that possible? If not prove it.

2) An infinite subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$ for which $S' = \emptyset$, that is, $S$ has no limit points. Is there such a set? If not provide a proof.

Answer (score 5):

First question: Let $\alpha$ be your least favourite irrational number. Let $U=(-\infty,\alpha)\cup (\alpha,\infty)$. Then $U$  is open, contains all rationals, and is not all of $\mathbb{R}$.

We can build more sophisticated examples, building open sets $U$ which contain the rationals and are quite "small" compared to $\mathbb{R}$.

Second question: Let $S=\mathbb{N}$, the set of natural numbers. This set is infinite but has no limit point.

Comment: "For any rational $r$, there is an open interval $I_r$ which contains $r$ and such that $I_r$ does not contain $\alpha$." Is this possible....if so could you give an example ?

Comment: Is it an example or you are trying to show it is not possible?

Comment: Your answer is all the rational number? Such as the example will be {2}?

Comment: So your said U = {all rational but is not all of R}. However, do you have a specific example? For your comment on Q2, what do you mean with what you said? Is a infinite set of 0 work?

Comment: Is U = {all rational number but is not all of R} same as U = {all rational number}?

Comment: No, $U$ contains many irrational points, remember, it is open, it is a union of a lot of intervals. I will change my answer, which was meant to lead you to more sophisticated examples. And I will delete the long string of comments, which the system does not like. Suggest you do the same.

Comment: What is the following:  "Let $U$=(-\infty,\alpha)\cup (\alpha,\infty)$. Then $U$  is open, contains all rationals, and is not all of $\mathbb{R}$. "?

Comment: Sorry, had to run, there was a TeX error, extra dollar sign.

Comment: -1 This is typically the kind of question for which the OP would benefit much more from hints and trying to solve the problem by her or himself rather than receiving a direct complete answer.

Comment: Possibly, but my feeling is that it is difficult enough for OP to understand a direct answer.

Comment: @ André Nicolas : I share your feeling and I agree that this is pedagogically debatable. My case : it is not always the case that a difficulty to understand even direct answer implies that it it preferable to be presented a direct answer. Being walked through the process of solving the problem may be a better way to eventually understand the final answer rather than proceeding backward and trying to understand a direct answer after it has been presented.

Comment: Possibly. I had erased my many comments. I I had not, you might see that the main difficulty is linguistic. Less direct answers have not been understood, I am experimenting with direct.

Comment: @ André Nicolas : as I did not see the comments, I did not realize the process you went through in answering the OP. Anyways, I think that the question of whether direct answers or hint benefit more struggling OP is an interesting one, so I opened a discussion on the meta on the topic http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11634/hint-versus-full-answer-when-the-op-is-struggeling.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

a) You need to find an open set such that it contains $\mathbb{Q}$ equivalently
you need to find a closed set which does not have any elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ and then take it's complement, how can you do that?

b) It would suffice if you could find an infinite set which had elements whose pairwise distance would be more than one, is there such a set?

Comment: When you said pair wise distance more than one, do you mean let pick a number 1. The pair wise distance of 1 bigger than 1 will be any number out of the range of 1.5 to 2.5?

Comment: yes then when you have picked the second number pick another which is away from both of the other points and the keep doing that